# How to write a regular expression for URLs

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I've been using the Regular Expression Explorer but I still can't come up with the right pattern.

Here's my URL:

```
http://pie.crust.com:18000/TEST/TEST.html
```

Here's my RegExp:

```
/[^http:\/\/][\w-\W]+[\/]/
```

And the output is:

```
ie.crust.com:18000/TEST/
```

All I want is the domain (basically everything inbetween // and /):

```
pie.crust.com:18000
```

What am I missing? I just can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem with using \w and \W is that the first says "any word character" while the second says "any non-word character" basically saying any character. In addition, your + was greedy and since \W contains \ (a literal backslash) it wanted to include the folders in the path, if you follow a + (or a *) with a ? then it means not to be greedy and to select the smallest number of characters that will validate the regex.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't realize why it was including folders in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part `[^http:\/\/]` is the same as `[^htp:\/]` and just enumerates all the characters which shouldn't be in the start part of the resulting string. So for `http://pie.crust.com:18000/TEST/TEST.html` `http://p` matches this enumeration. I suggest you the following expression:

```
/http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/.*/
```

You can use [`String.replace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) the following way:

```
var myUrl:String = "http://pie.crust.com:18000/TEST/TEST.html";
var refinedUrl:String = myUrl.replace(/http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/.*/, "$1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: `http:\/\/([^\/]+)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@http://+(.*?)/@
```

(Your regexp doesn't have to start and end with `/` - it's easier to use something else that isn't in your search string.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=http:\/\/)[a-zA-Z.:0-9-]+`

The p of "pie" is being matched as part of the http rule, and so is not included.  Using a positive look-behind fixed this.

http://regexr.com?2uhjf

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was using a different RegEx builder but this one is great.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this...
//http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/.***/
```